# How to insert a type between all elements of a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I have:

```
struct spacer : foo<bar>{};

struct sequence : baz<qux, spacer, quz, spacer, plugh>{};
```

I would like to be able to write (something like this, exact syntax doesn't matter):

```
struct spaced_sequence : SPACED_BAZ<qux, quz, plugh>{};
```

Can this be done with macros/templates/anything else?

Comment: To potentially add some clarity / avoid close votes - you are asking how to make `SPACED_BAZ` have the same meaning as `baz`, with some template arguments omitted, because they are assumed to be `spacer`.  Correct?

Comment: Anything to "solve" this would undoubtedly include a lot more typing than adding two "spacer" parameters. Is `baz` your class? In that case perhaps move the less used template parameters to the end and add ´= spacer` defaults.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes.

Comment: @BoP This is a simplified example, there are more than two and it needs to be done multiple times. baz is not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

Create a base case function template that appends a single type `T` to some specialization of `baz`

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto append(baz<Args...>) -> baz<Args..., T>;
```

Note that no `spacer` is added here, since `T` is the last type we're adding.

Then write a recursive case, also as a function template, that gets called if there are at least 2 more types `T1`, and `T2` that need to be added

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Rest, typename ... Args>
auto append(baz<Args...>) 
  -> decltype(append<T2, Rest...>(std::declval<baz<Args..., T1, spacer>>()));
                                      // insert spacer after T1 ^
                  // ^ pass the remaining types recursively
```

and finally add a convenience alias

```
template<typename ...Ts>
using SPACED_BAZ = decltype(append<Ts...>(std::declval<baz<>>()));
                   // types to add ^  and baz is empty to start
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/38dG5Kjx9).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (assuming know number of arguments):

```
template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
using SPACED_BAZ = baz<T1, spacer, T2, spacer, T3>;
```

If you have more type, you can do other alias as required.